# Lost in Translation

Tags: word, cipher

*You arrive on a foreign island, but upon heading to the local library, you find yourself unable to decipher the texts. You wonder what's caused this...*

```
                          ???????????????????????????????????
           B H        F K    QCEI     MT   N UWO S OR  VEGU    LT  R  YZ               
                              AJ      H    P        X     O           O                
                                      D             E                                  

                          ????????????????????????????????
  A      B          K FDP C          I   I JYX  VET NG O L  Z  O  U   R             
                        M                   OE    I         S         U             
                        H                   W     Q                                 

                          ?????????????????????????????
           B  H F        P D SI   JN   Q  XOLG      E  UT  R U WY                
           A    A            K     C        M              Z    O                
                                                           V                     

                          ????????????????????????????
  A                F H     MB   PJKWNL QC TG ZI O S E  R     X     U            
                                 D        I  Y         U                        
                                                       V                        

                          ??????????????????????????
          ABFD     J  M C   K      GW  P NO   S LR V Y   X  T   U Z           
                            H                   E  I                          
                                                Q                             

                          ??????????????????????????
                          ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

<sub>Hint level 0</sub>

> I went up to the librarian and queried, "Are these in English?"
>  "Of course they are," she irritably replied.

<sub>Hint level 1</sub>

> "But I can't read them!"
>  "Yes, you'll need to translate what's on the page before you can read it."

<sub>Hint level 2</sub>

> "You just said they were in English!"
>  "Go and *reflect* on your attempts, and if you still can't do it ask the librarian on the next *rotation*."

<sub>Hint level 3</sub>

> I asked the next librarian, "Ok, I think I know what to do now... but how do I start?"
>  "May I refer you DUN - Ella Minnow Pea?"

<sub>Hint level 4</sub>

> Before I could ask the librarian for some more advice, he proffered, "I believe the first line is about a brown fox? And the second about some liquor jugs?"

Comment: Any more hints?

Comment: @RAZ369 Just posted another.

Comment: Is there another hint?

Comment: @Bee Sure, there's one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To decipher the text,

> each letter must be moved horizontally by an amount specific to each letter. To determine the exact offsets, you can write `thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog` over the `?` in the first line and compare with the letters below it. The offsets are:
>
> ```
>  |A +25|J +11|S - 3|
>  |B +23|K + 9|T -13|
>  |C + 2|L - 9|U -15|
>  |D +20|M + 6|V - 7|
>  |E - 3|N - 5|W - 9|
>  |F +17|O -11|X -11|
>  |G + 3|P + 2|Y -13|
>  |H +14|Q   0|Z -15|
>  |I - 1|R -17|
> ```

The text deciphers to:

> `TheQuickBrownFoxJumpsOverTheLazyDog`
>
>  `PackMyBoxWithFiveDozenLiquorJugs`
>
>  `SphinxOfBlackQuartzJudgeMyVow`
>
>  `WaltzNymphForQuickJigsVexBud`
>
>  `CwmFjordBankGlyphsVextQuiz`
>
>  `Relocutingzyxwvsqpmkjhfdba`

Comment: Nice job! As a minor nitpick, you haven't quite answered the question "You wonder what's caused this...", although the answer's in your post.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a full answer but advances on the hints.

The book 'Ella Minnow Pea' by Mark Dunn (DUN).
In this book there is a pangram (sentence or phrase including every letter of the alphabet): 'pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs'. There is another; 'the quick, brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

Then there is statement: 'you must translate what is on the page'. This doesn't mean literal translation but mathematical translation. This is then hinted at when the librarian says '*reflect* on your attempts' and 'the next *rotation*.

Please feel free to work off of this :)

Comment: Nice. Do you mind putting your progress in spoiler blocks, please?